# How to find positive integer solution of bilinear transformation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $y = (ax + b)/(cx + d)$, where $a, b, c, d$ are known integer constants, is there any technique to find positive integer solution of $x, y$? is there any iterative method approach without using factorization?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176206/how-to-find-integer-solution-for-bilinear-transformation.

Answer (score 1):

Equation;

$$y=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$

Decisions are not always there. To find out, I use too much.  Decompose the multiplier number.

$$(t-k)(t+k)=4(da-bc)$$

Finding the number $t$ and $k$, the solution writes:

$$x=\frac{k-2d+t}{2c}$$

$$y=\frac{k+2a-t}{2c}$$

Comment: Is there any iterative method approach without using factorization since factorization has no polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: @Kadi  this approach is more effective.  Calculations less.  And it is clear how to find solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to solve this equation is by factoring.

If a different way is found to solve this equation, it would be equivalent to factoring.

y=(ax+b) / (cx+d)

y(c x + d) = (a x + b)

c x y + d y - a x = b

p q = (b c - a d)

c^2 x y + c d y - c a x = b c

c^2 x y + c d y - c a x - a d = b c - a d

(c x   + d ) (c y - a ) = b c - a d

Let p q = b c - a d

(c x   + d = q

(c y - a ) = p

x = (q - d)/c

y = (p + a) / c