# How to find integer solution for bilinear transformation?

Tags: number-theory

Let y = (ax + b)/(cx + d), where a, b, c, d integer constants, is there any technique to find integer solution of x & y?

Comment: Hint: consider $cy-a$.

Comment: I would say this question is better suited to math.stackexchange.

Comment: posted to stackexchange. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176099/how-to-find-positive-integer-solution-of-bilinear-transformation.