# is it possible to find $x$ where $y$ is equal to a whole number in a non iterative fashion

Tags: diophantine-equations, computational-mathematics

Given the equation

$$\frac{635x+326}{637+x} = y$$

where $$x>0$$

Is it possible to find all positive values of $x$ (there is only one) where $x$ is positive and $y$ is a whole number.

While I can iterate all positive values of $x$, I was hoping to shortcut that as the values of x are expected to be huge.

The answer for the above equation is
$x=40$ .: $y=38$

Comment: $$y=635-404169/(637+x)$$ 637+x must be a divisor of $404169$, so...

Comment: Yes I tried that approach. All I got was every integer except -637 was valid.

Comment: An algorithm would just find the divisors $d_i$ of $404169$ and then set $x_i=d_i-637$. That would find all solutions.

Comment: Because the values of x are huge its not practical to factor in a timely fashion. I was hoping for a polynomial solution. but I can now see that it is not possible.

Comment: Any solution to this problem(with arbitrary coefficients) would solve an arbitrary factoring with the same complexity. You can trivially test all divisors in $O(\sqrt{d})$ time. How *huge* are those numbers going to be?

Comment: We are talking in the realm of 128bits Sometimes higher. I have found this. seems workable but to be honest its voodoo to me. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8629/fastest-semiprime-factorization

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a similar question. And I don't think you can avoid iterating to find a solution.

[How to find positive integer solution of bilinear transformation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1176099/how-to-find-positive-integer-solution-of-bilinear-transformation)